# React-Native - Email Input with suggestions - iOS 16

Tags: ios, react-native, email

How is it possible to add a suggestion to email fields? I tried with "textContentType" and read some answers posted in the internet, but without a solution.

I use React-Native 0.70.6 and iOS 16

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/custom-suggestion-inputs-with-react-native-typescript-and-context-api-aade4dcd5cb5 here example you can refer and also see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62993032/how-to-get-suggestions-while-typing-in-text-input-in-react-native